# Top level URL form validation

Tags: javascript, php

How to validate or filter with java script (or PHP) TOP level URL/domain only?
And it has to accept also new domain extensions, for example:

this is correct:
http://www.something.bid
etc...

and this is not correct:
http://www.example1.com/blahblah/etc/something/index.php
etc...

ALSO Subdomains - NOT ALLOWED!

It will be validated with java script or PHP in my input form.
Many thanks!

Comment: This is a valid "TLD" domain, so why its not correct.
http:/ /www.example1.com/blahblah/etc/something/index.php

Comment: @Ibrahim Because I don't want to accept subdomain or domain.com/slash/something.html sites on my list, I want just full level domain like 'thisisfine.com' or 'www.thisisfine.com' or 'http:/ /thisisfine.com' and nothing after it like http:/ /www.example1.com/blahblah/etc/something/index.php or http:/ /www.example2.com/index.php etc.

Comment: @Ibrahim Also, nothing before it (no subdomains!).

Answer (score 0):

OK, 
TLD Means : `.com`, `.org`, `.net` etc...

Sub Domain Means : `www.NAME`, `dev.DOMAIN_NAME`, etc...

SO URL IS  `[SUB_DOMAIN].domain_name.[TLD]/[Extra URL PATH|QUERY_PARAMS]`

Which qualifies `www.something.bd` , `www` is a subdomain, Probably you want to make an exception for `www` subdomain.

Use this regex to match the url, 
`/(https?:\/\/)?(([0-9a-z\_-]+)\.)?([a-z0-9\_-]+)\.([a-z]{2,})\/?(\/.+)?/`

Sample

```
var matches = 'http://www.something.bid'.match(/(https?:\/\/)?(([0-9a-z\_-]+)\.)?([a-z0-9\_-]+)\.([a-z]{2,})\/?(\/.+)?/)
```

Result

> > ["http://www.something.bid", "http://", "www.", "www", "something", "bid", undefined]

```
matches[3] == sub-domain
matches[4] == domain
matches[5] == tld name
matches[6] == rest path
```

You can now check if sub-domain to be empty or specific value.

```js
function checkUrl(url){
  var regx = /(https?:\/\/)?(([0-9a-z\_-]+)\.)?([a-z0-9\_-]+)\.([a-z]{2,})\/?(.+)?/;
  var matches = url.match( regx );

  if ( matches.length == 7 
      && (!matches[3] || matches[3] == 'www') 
      && matches[4] 
      && matches[5] 
      && !matches[6] ) 
    return true;

  return false;
}


alert(checkUrl("http://something.bid/"));

alert(checkUrl("http://www.example1.com/blahblah/etc/something/index.php"));
```

Happy Coding... :-)

Comment: hm. seems that I need alternative method, because it have not to affect just one url like "http://www.something.bid" but all possible (users have to add their URLs...), etc. Thanks anyway.